# Cant echo date null field

Tags: php

I am currently using php to connect the tables in my ms sql database to appear on my webpage.The table appears however im having issues with the date fields that are null in my sql table.

The table is a garage repair for vehicles.

```
 create table [VEHICLE_STATUS](
 [STATUS_ID] [int] identity (1,1) not null,
 [VEHICLE_ID] [INT]  not null, 
 [REPAIR_START_DATE] [DATE] not  null,
 [REPAIR_END_DATE] [DATE] not null,
 [DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar] (200) not null
 );
```

However not all the vehicles are in for repair thus have no repair start or end dates.

I have tried to change the date fields to change to "available" instead of null

The error that comes up is;

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\view.php on line 57

```
    <?php
            $server = "\SQLEXPRESS";
        $options = array( "Database"=>"test" );


        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $options );


        if( !$conn ) die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ) );

$query = "select * from VW_VEHICLE_STATUS";
$sql = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);


            echo "<table >";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;Font-size=18;Font-weight=bold'>";
            echo "MAKE";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;Font-size=18;Font-Weight=bold'>";
            echo "MODEL";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;Font-size=18;Font-Weight=bold'>";
            echo "REGISTRATION";
            echo "</td>";
               echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;Font-size=18;Font-Weight=bold'>";
            echo "REPAIR_START_DATE";
            echo "</td>";
               echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;Font-size=18;Font-Weight=bold'>";
            echo "REPAIR_END_DATE";
            echo "</td>";
               echo "<td style='border:1px solid black;Font-size=18;Font-Weight=bold'>";
            echo "DESCRIPTION";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>\n";

           while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql)) 
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>";
                echo $row['MAKE']; 
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>";
                echo $row['MODEL']; 
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>";
                echo $row['REGISTRATION']; 
                echo "</td>";
                     echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>";
                echo $row['REPAIR_START_DATE']->format("Y-M-d"); 
                echo "</td>";
                     echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>";
                echo $row['REPAIR_END_DATE']->format("Y-M-d"); ; 
                echo "</td>";
                   echo "<td style='border:1px solid black'>";
                echo $row['DESCRIPTION']; 
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>\n";
            }
            echo "</table>";

            sqlsrv_close( $conn);
            ?>
```

Comment: What is the point of showing some sql when your error message is a PHP error? "hey doctor, I broke my leg and it's squirting blood and bone fragments everywhere. Here's a picture of my car so you can figure out how to fix me"

Comment: @Jane- you need to consider posting your PHP code at that line shown in the error and tag it PHP for better responses

Comment: The most possible issue might be not-checking for nulls before you use format of date column

Comment: thank you for your constructive feedback Marc B.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if date is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461928/check-if-date-is-empty)

Comment: database: you mentioned that not all vehicles have repair start or end dates, I would change the fields [REPAIR_START_DATE] and  [REPAIR_END_DATE] to allow nulls.
php: then check if row date is  null or not before formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check if the value is an instance of *DateTime* before calling *format* method on it.

```
echo $row['REPAIR_END_DATE'] instanceof DateTime ? $row['REPAIR_END_DATE']->format('Y-m-d') : '';
```